# Has the manifestation of ideas been explored before?

Tags: epistemology

I'm trying to figure out whether the manifestation of ideas has been explored before. It's similar to Richard Dawkin's concept of memes, but I'm not quite sure if it is the same.

Suppose an individual has an idea pop into their mind. This can be considered the idea manifesting itself to an individual.

Then the individual writes it down in a book. The idea has manifested itself in the book.

The book convinces hundreds of people of the idea. The idea manifested itself to  all of those people.

Suppose that the idea is about how the legal system should be. The idea manifests itself by being instantiated in law and permanently impacting society.

Alternatively, the idea is about going to war with another nation. The idea manifests itself as a war and also manifests itself as a permanent influence on the history of nations.

It seems to me that ideas can perform actions on the world by manifesting themselves. What would this be called? Has it been explored before?

Comment: An alternate approach may be through Sheldrake's Morphic Resonance and Fields: https://www.sheldrake.org/research/morphic-resonance/introduction

Comment: Yes, and it is very old. Plato called it [imitation (*mimesis*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_forms), of ideas by sensible things. Of course, the modern view is that ideas manifesting, popping into minds, etc., are just turns of phrase. Ideas do not really do anything, they do not even exist, they are just a shorthand way to talk about actions that do.

Comment: Cf. Hyperstition

Comment: @K Pomykala- The phenomenon which you describe demonstrates Spinoza recognition of what he termed, idea, ideas. An idea as it exists in a mind is real and the proof of that, as in your examples is that it can be 'conveyed' to another person. Your term, 'manifests itself', is a perf

Comment: That's just called creativity and/or imagination (your definition is not clear, you talk about ideas as active entities, not passive objects, which must be the case). Yes, there's a lot about it. E.g. https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/imagination/

Answer (score 1):

The majority of mathematicians consider math to be a real thing, discovered, not created.  Most ethics thinking holds that morality is a real thing, as all objective morality presupposes its existence.  These are the two most common examples of the application of abstract object realism to a subject.

Quine agrees that abstract object realism is as fully inferred from the utility of abstract objects, as physical reality is inferred by the same method.

The most extensive thinking I have seen on the nature of abstract objects is by Karl Popper, who proposed that our universe has three types of things in it:  matter, experience, and ideas.  He proposed that these are three different worlds, world 1 which is physical, world 2 which is consciousness, and world 3 which is ideas. Frege was the first proposer of these three worlds, and Popper elaborated on them.

Popper's model of the interaction of ideas with matter, was that consciousness was the intermediary.  The ability of a conscious entity to hypothesize what might happen provides a material entity the ability to experiment in a theory space that is less damaging to its life.  Consciousness would then serve a materiel entity, and allow a material entity to benefit from world 3 ideas.

Meme theory takes world 3 even more seriously, and assumes that world 3 memes control the world 2 consciousness, and from there, the world 1 entities that hold consciousness.  The idea of Libertie, Fraternitie, Equalitie, for example, spawned a series of revolutions and wars, and lead to the democratization of Europe.

Comment: "The majority of mathematicians consider math to be a real thing". Not anymore, "*More  than  60 %  of  the  university  
teachers  clearly  view  in  mathematics  the formalism 
aspect and  a  high  degree  of  formal  strictness  
(45.7%  mostly,  15.5  %  completely)... Almost 58 % of the  university teachers  reject  the  view  of  a  Platonism  aspect  in  mathematics, 34.6  %  on  the  whole  and  even  23.3  %  completely*", [Grigutsch-Törner survey](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0db7/f57b616720d56d26eac43fa112bd8959de08.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

This is very close to Dawkins' notion, except that he assumes this layer and theorizes that the manifesting ideas are like reproducing creatures, and that they may therefore have constituent parts corresponding to the genes that determine physical creatures.  Those 'elementary sub-ideas' are the memes.

Daniel Dennett buys into the theory of memes, and is trying to build `[a philosophically sound approach that includes it][1]`.

He is a hard-core materialist, so he often prefers to frame this in terms of sub-cultures and cultural evolution, talking about ideas 'being introduced' and 'transferring among groups'.  But this is the same mechanism as your manifestation or Platonic 'participation' with the shared mind, but from a behaviorist POV.

Comment: what even is behaviorism?

Comment: The POV that it is pointless to discuss ideas or other cognitive events unless you can firmly tie the reported internal events to a pattern of external behavior.

Comment: How can a 'hard core materialist' speak about ideas having an effect on the world?

Comment: @PeterJ  If you cannot see that connection it is because of your own biases.  Just because people look at things differently and describe them in different terms that does not make absolutely everything they have to say on every topic completely useless to one another.  For instance, postmodernists notions of 'cultural evolution' and Platonic/psychoanalytic 'participation in the shared mind' cover the same set of objective facts (how expressed ideas travel) and can still shed light on one another.  Your dislike of materialists just keeps you from giving a dam what they say.

Comment: makes sense, thanks @jobermark

Comment: @another_name  (Sorry I forgot the tag.)

Comment: @jobermark not why i am able to haha

Comment: @jobermark - I struggle to see what motivates your comment. I repeat - How can a hard-core materialist talk about ideas having an effect on the world? This is a question and as such has nothing to do with my opinions .

Comment: @PeterJ  Ideas obviously exist, even for a hard-core materialist.  Materialism does not just contradict everyday experience, and everyday experience involves ideas.  He can then discuss them, and their effects.  They just have to take some form other than the only one you seem willing to take seriously.  Refusing to take other perspectives seriously is not reasonable.

Comment: @jobermark  A hardcore materialist who concedes the reality of ideas is an oxymoron in my view. Materialism contradicts my everyday experience in that it denies experience unless it is physical, and the idea of a physical experience is not something I can take seriously.  I don't take perspectives seriously unless they seem to deserve it. What about my question? It';s no use just saying that materialists can talk about ideas. Of course they can, just as atheists can talk about God.   .

Comment: @PeterJ  You can define people out of existence all you want.  They will continue existing.  You have no way of knowing whether or not your experience is physical.  None whatsoever.  I am sorry that you don't consider most perspectives I have worth taking seriously.  But if you have already decided not to take me seriously -- then do not talk to me.

Comment: @jobermark - I think your suggestion is a good one. It was your choice to get all upset with my simple and reasonable question and start insulting me. You have now answered in the only way possible, which is to note that materialists must assume experience is physical. Do you expect me to take this idea seriously? I just laugh at it. It explains exactly nothing but just protects a dogma. I'm not interested in dogma, especially when it causes cognitive dissonance and explains exactly nothing. . ..

Comment: @PeterJ -- the opposite of a dogma is a dogma, when you treat it like one.  I am telling you what a given group of people say, and you are aswering that the given group of people does not exist.  Well, that defies *my* everyday experience of actually knowing them.  That is kind of insane...  The concept of cultural evolution is an interesting one, and we would not have gotten there except through the materialist lens.  Whether or not the *path* is right, the idea laid out in the answer is useful and should be pursued.

Comment: @jobermark - I can genuinely and honestly say I do not know how your comment is relevant or what it means. When did I say a group of people does not exist? Why are we arguing when all I did was ask a question? Why don't we both agree that our views are so far apart that our discussions are futile?

Comment: @PeterJ You dismissed my answer to your question with  "A hardcore materialist who concedes the reality of ideas is an oxymoron"  Claiming that such people do not exist.  We are arguing because you seem to me both amazingly careless and bizarrely condescending.  Materialists need to deal with what ideas really are, if they do not accord them the supernatural existence you assume.  But they do a creditable job of giving answers to that question.  And you seem totally unwilling to admit that work ever takes place.  More importantly, the work involve creates interesting concepts - like the answer

Comment: @Jobermark - I do not claim such people do not exist. I claim that it is impossible to reconcile in logic strong materialism and the causal efiicacy of ideas. Hence the term 'oxymoron'. . .

Comment: @PeterJ  But the rest of that response is false too.  Materialism does not deny anything exists.  It tries to give physical interpretation to those things.  You are just redefining the word to make it easier to laugh at.  Derision is low

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99101/discussion-between-peterj-and-jobermark).

Answer (score 0):

The Vedas contain fragments of an ancient science of consciousness that, once recognized, elucidated and couched in modern language, are very similar to answers given above.

An attempt to describe it must use modern terms that are, at best, rough approximations to the concepts. Simplistically put, Vedic ideas conceive of the Physical Realm in which ideas find material expression, and so can "bang against each other"; the Psychic Realm in which they are energy constructs that can encounter and merge, like aspects mutually strengthening and unlike aspects weakening, so that their interactions determine the strongest by what remains of the encounter; and the Spiritual Realm in which live a multitude of creative ... Logoi shall we say ... that avail themselves of these opportunities, first to use the Psychic Realm to determine the most robust ideas, and then to attempt material realization in a suitable environment, typically the biosphere of an amenable planet.

I doubt that any of this is known to Readers here, but it may be useful as a new path of exploration.